# Elements not being added to list in for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Why are the elements given by the user not being added to the list? Instead, the list is counting up.

```
list1 =[]
print("How much numbers")
x =int(input())
print("input numbers:")
for n in range(x):
        int(input())
        y =list1.append(n)


print(list1)   



"""
output:

[0,1,2,3]
"""
```

Comment: What is the expected input and expected output here? @Coa__00__

Comment: What should I do when someone answers my question? @Coa__00__

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the value of `int(input(..))` to a variable, and append that variable to the list `list1` for your code to work

```
list1 =[]
print("How much numbers")
x =int(input())
print("input numbers:")
for n in range(x):
    #Take input and assign to z
    z = int(input())
    #Append z to list
    y = list1.append(z)

print(list1)
```

The output will that be

```
How much numbers
4
input numbers:
1
2
3
4
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Great!  Glad to help @Coa__00__ Please consider accepting my answer if it helped you by clicking the tick next to the answer :)